# Colocar en el where mismo campo diferente valor

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tengo el siguiente query:

```
(SELECT sno_hpersonalnomina.codnom, count(distinct(sno_hpersonalnomina.codper)), trunc(cast(sum(ABS(sno_hsalida.valsal)) as numeric), 2) as asigna
from sno_hpersonalnomina 
inner JOIN sno_hsalida ON sno_hpersonalnomina.codnom = sno_hsalida.codnom 
AND sno_hpersonalnomina.codper = sno_hsalida.codper 
and sno_hpersonalnomina.codperi= sno_hsalida.codperi
where sno_hpersonalnomina.codper::int= 116052 and sno_hpersonalnomina.codperi::int= 019 
and sno_hpersonalnomina.codnom::integer <= 8 and sno_hpersonalnomina.staper::int=1 and sno_hsalida.tipsal='A' 
group by sno_hpersonalnomina.codnom)

UNION all

(SELECT sno_hpersonalnomina.codnom, count(distinct(sno_hpersonalnomina.codper)), trunc(cast(sum(ABS(sno_hsalida.valsal)) as numeric), 2) as deducciones
from sno_hpersonalnomina 
inner JOIN sno_hsalida ON sno_hpersonalnomina.codnom = sno_hsalida.codnom 
AND sno_hpersonalnomina.codper = sno_hsalida.codper 
and sno_hpersonalnomina.codperi= sno_hsalida.codperi
where sno_hpersonalnomina.codper::int= 116052 and sno_hpersonalnomina.codperi::int= 019 
and sno_hpersonalnomina.codnom::integer <= 8 and sno_hpersonalnomina.staper::int=1 and (sno_hsalida.tipsal='D' or sno_hsalida.tipsal='P1') 
group by sno_hpersonalnomina.codnom)
```

Resultado

```
codnom  TRABAJADORES  ASIGNACIONES
-----------------------------------
0001        1           193397.27
0001        1           24831.02
```

Pero el problema es que el campo tipsal tiene valor A para asignaciones y para las deducciones tiene valor P1 Y D.

Como hago para plasmar eso en el query?

Este es el resultado de lo que se requiere

```
codnom  TRABAJADORES  ASIGNACIONES DEDUCCIONES TOTAL_NETO
---------------------------------------------------------      
 1        20         200000         100000      100000
 2        10         150000         50000       100000
```

Comment: hola Rafael. Por favor ponte en nuestro lugar, o sea, el lugar de alguien que no conoce nada de tus tablas y los datos que se encuentran en estos. La pregunta asume mucho conocimiento de nuestra parte. Por favor agrega todos los detalles necesarios para que tengamos el cuedro completo.

Comment: mil disculpas, codnom es el codigo de una nomina, aqui se manejan grupos de nomina en el cual cada empleado esta metido alli, trabajadores son la cantidad de trabajadores de cada nomina, asignaciones son todas las remuneraciones sueldos, primas, etc y deducciones, son todos las deducciones q t aplican como trabajdor, es decir, algun descuento, seguro social, etc.

Comment: el campo tipsal es el campo q diferencia si es deduccion o asignacion, lo cual si es asignacion el campo es tipo a y si es deduccion es P1 y D. El campo valsal es el q almacena los montos bien sea deduccion o asignacion, el tipsal es el q hace la diferencia

Comment: La tabla snohpersonal es la tabla q almacena todos los trabajadores, la tabla hsalida es en donde esta los montos de los trabajadores

Comment: @RafaelAguilar, la idea es que edites tu pregunta y hagas las aclaraciones ahí. También sería bueno que pongas un ejemplo con la definición y el contenido (parcial) de las tablas, además de tu query para que podamos probarla. Para ello se puede usar sqlfiddle o rextester. Te paso un ejemplo: http://rextester.com/EESKX21438 Al grabar queda un link permanente que se puede pegar en la pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pareciera que en tu ejemplo te estás limitando a un trabajador específico

```
where sno_hpersonalnomina.codper::int= 116052 
and sno_hpersonalnomina.codperi::int= 019 
and sno_hpersonalnomina.codnom::integer <= 8
```

Pasando esas cláusulas por alto, y suponiendo que cada trabajador tiene un `codper` único, y que dos o más trabajadores pueden tener el mismo `codnom` la query que debieras hacer para llegar a un resultado como el que quieres es:

```
SELECT codnom,
       count(DISTINCT codper) AS trabajadores,
       SUM(CASE WHEN sno_hsalida.tipsal='A' THEN ABS(sno_hsalida.valsal::numeric) ELSE 0 END) AS asignaciones,
       SUM(CASE WHEN sno_hsalida.tipsal='A' THEN 0 ELSE ABS(sno_hsalida.valsal::numeric) END) AS deducciones,
       SUM((CASE WHEN sno_hsalida.tipsal='A' THEN 1 ELSE -1 END)*ABS(sno_hsalida.valsal::numeric)) AS total_neto
FROM sno_hsalida
GROUP BY codnom
```

De nuevo, esto suponiendo que N trabajadores pueden tener el mismo `codnom`. Dependiendo del significado de `codper` puede que la cantidad de trabajadores debas obtenerla del `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` de otro campo

Comment: Buen día, gracias @amenadiel, si es el resultado, sin embargo, tengo una duda despues del case when yo puedo colocar otra condiciones? te explico, la suma d asignaciones me da muy alto, dedusco que sea porq m falta colocar mas filtros..

Comment: si, codper es el codigo unico d  cada trabajador y codnom es el grupo d donde pertenece a dicho trabajador

Comment: si, m limito a uno para q sea un poco mas facil y asi veo si los montos estan correctos o no, por eso t pregunto si puedo coocar otra condiciones o filtros, ya q es primera vez q manejo en un query lo case, gracias hermano!

Comment: Puedes agregar condiciones mediante la cláusula `WHERE` pero todo depende de qué quieres obtener. También puedes añadir más condiciones al `CASE`, de manera de descartar resultados que no cumplan una cierta condición. Si la suma de asignaciones te da muy alta, muéstranos el contenido de las filas para los trabajadores de `codnom` 1 y 2 a ver qué está fallando.

Comment: Ya logre poner las condiciones, ahora estoy viendo como sacar el total_neto q es el total tipsal A - el total tipsal P1 or D. Pero la respuesta anterior me iluminó.

Comment: Bueno, el total neto lo calculo como la suma de ABS(sno_hsalida.valsal::numeric) * 1 o -1. El signo depende del tipsal

Comment: amenadiel porq se multiplica * 1 o se coloca el signo? Saludos y feliz navidad

Comment: Porque el valor va en una misma columna y no me consta si los aportes son positivos y los otros negativos. Sin poder asumir eso, para que se resten entre sí le pongo el signo usando el valor de `tipsal`al valor absoluto de `valsal`. Puede que no sea necesario. Feliz navidad y próspero año para ti tamién ;)